# Remove duplicate rows in a table having no primary key

Tags: mysql, distinct, duplicates

I have a table item that contains items like

```
name
------
alpha
alpha 
beta
charlie
charlie
```

In this case how would I delete duplicate rows but one record should remain. The above table does not have any primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM item WHERE GREATEST(0,@num := IF(NAME = @NAME, @num + 1, 0),LEAST(0, LENGTH(@NAME := NAME)))>0
```

Answer (score 1):

Recreate that table:

```
RENAME TABLE `testTable` TO `testTable2`;

CREATE TABLE `testTable` 
SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `testTable2`;
```

**OR** Add **UNIQUE INDEX** on your field.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `tableName` 
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`name`)
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to apply unique index. I just want to execute query that should remove the duplicate rows.

Comment: @sureyn: but if you do not apply a unique key, you'll have the same problem again. It's better to prevent that situation rather than cleaning up constantly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are correct but my concern is to just execute delete query to remove duplicate rows except one record. BTW my issue is resolved and many thanks for your help.

Comment: what if we have more columns?