# To delete duplicate from a table where there is no key(unique) column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table which looks like this.

```
date          time     open     high      low      close
2015-11-24   09:30     7848.7   7848.75   7813.9   7820.35
2015-11-24   09:31     7820.7   7829.75   7820.9   7826.35
2015-11-24   09:32     7826.7   7831.75   7824.9   7831.35
2015-11-24   09:33     7831.7   7837.75   7831.9   7836.35
.....
..... total 375 rows
2015-11-24   15:29     7833.45   7834.45  7831.0    7833.6
```

One of my python codes which inserts rows to this table ran twice accidentally so it just created duplicate of those 375 rows in the table. Finally my table looks like below now.

```
  date          time     open     high      low      close
2015-11-24   09:30     7848.7   7848.75   7813.9   7820.35
2015-11-24   09:31     7820.7   7829.75   7820.9   7826.35
2015-11-24   09:32     7826.7   7831.75   7824.9   7831.35
2015-11-24   09:33     7831.7   7837.75   7831.9   7836.35
.....
..... 
2015-11-24   15:29     7833.45   7834.45  7831.0    7833.6
+(Duplicate entries since my code inserted  twice)    
2015-11-24   09:30     7848.7   7848.75   7813.9   7820.35
2015-11-24   09:31     7820.7   7829.75   7820.9   7826.35
2015-11-24   09:32     7826.7   7831.75   7824.9   7831.35
2015-11-24   09:33     7831.7   7837.75   7831.9   7836.35
.....
..... 
2015-11-24   15:29     7833.45   7834.45  7831.0    7833.6
```

Now, I want to remove the duplicate entries which were inserted to table for the second time accidentally. How can I achieve this using SQL queries?

Comment: Why is there no primary key?

Comment: Datetime (which should of course be a single column) looks like an obvious contender

Comment: Also, I'm looking at your data and can't really find the duplicates.  Can you point them out?

Comment: Because my code was supposed to run only once a day and insert only 375 rows every day. So I taught primary key wasn't required. Accidentaly today my programm ran twice and inserted same 375 rows twice. And the challenge I am facing now is to delete the duplicate rows since there are no primary keys as my question header says.

Comment: You might be able to use Microsoft Access and a link to your mysql table.  Try it with test data first.  You might end up deleting both records instead of 1.

Comment: Make sure you fix your insert query to prevent recurrence.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357888/remove-duplicate-rows-in-a-table-having-no-primary-key (Remove duplicate rows in a table having no primary key)

Answer (score 0):

first check how to find physical location of row in mySQL and then replace %%Physloc%% with mySQL physical location keyword.

Delete From Test_SO
    Where %%Physloc%% not in
    (Select MIN(%%Physloc%%)
    From Test_SO
    Group by [Date]
          ,[source]
          ,[company]
          ,[Person])